# Scraping dynamic data selenium - Unable to locate element

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selenium, web-scraping

I am very new to scraping and have a question. I am scraping worldometers covid data. As it is dynamic - I am doing it with selenium.

The code is the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

URL = "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/"

# Start the Driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r"C:\Webdriver\chromedriver.exe")
# Hit the url and wait for 10 seconds.
driver.get(URL)
time.sleep(10)
#find class element
data= driver.find_elements_by_class_name("odd" and "even")
#for loop
for d in data:
    country=d.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='main_table_countries_today']").text
    print(country)
```

current output:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='main_table_countries_today']"}
  (Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.45)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62302639/pandas-no-tables-found-matching-pattern   I am tempted to close as duplicate though you want selenium answer it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To scrape table within [worldometers covid data](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) and using [*DataFrame*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70126393/selenium-web-scraping-historical-data-from-coincodex-and-transform-into-a-panda/70128927#70128927) from [*Pandas*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70158178/scraping-and-writing-the-table-into-dataframe-shows-me-typeerror/70165627#70165627) you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

Code Block:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
s = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
driver.get("https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/")
data = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table#main_table_countries_today"))).get_attribute("outerHTML")
df  = pd.read_html(data)
print(df)
driver.quit()
```

Console Output:

```
[         # Country,Other  TotalCases  NewCases  ...  Deaths/1M pop   TotalTests  Tests/ 1M pop    Population
0      NaN         World   264359298  632349.0  ...          673.3          NaN            NaN           NaN
1      1.0           USA    49662381   89259.0  ...         2415.0  756671013.0      2267182.0  3.337495e+08
2      2.0         India    34609741    3200.0  ...          336.0  643510926.0       459914.0  1.399198e+09
3      3.0        Brazil    22118782   12910.0  ...         2865.0   63776166.0       297051.0  2.146975e+08
4      4.0            UK    10329074   53945.0  ...         2124.0  364875273.0      5335159.0  6.839070e+07
..     ...           ...         ...       ...  ...            ...          ...            ...           ...
221  221.0         Samoa           3       NaN  ...            NaN          NaN            NaN  2.002800e+05
222  222.0  Saint Helena           2       NaN  ...            NaN          NaN            NaN  6.103000e+03
223  223.0    Micronesia           1       NaN  ...            NaN          NaN            NaN  1.167290e+05
224  224.0         Tonga           1       NaN  ...            NaN          NaN            NaN  1.073890e+05
225    NaN        Total:   264359298  632349.0  ...          673.3          NaN            NaN           NaN

[226 rows x 15 columns]]
```